# get newly added element's id DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I am adding image from php using ajax.
I want to process image after getting it on DOM.
I am able to load the image. but I cannot figure it out how to detect in jquery for newly inserted DOM element.

I tried with this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).parent()[0].tagName);
});
```

But, It's little bit different thing.

Comment: Are you at least getting an alert triggered?

Comment: yes. I am getting alert for all the elements . not newly inserted. and I want that element's id.

Answer (score 1):

For elements loaded post DOM load, you can use `bind()` or `on()`

http://api.jquery.com/on/
https://api.jquery.com/bind/

It would be helpful if you provided more details on what you are trying to do exactly.